# Using EF 4, POCO and LINQ; what is the cleanest way to select from ManyToMany relationships?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm trying to find the cleanest way to retrieve data from a many-to-many structure.

My example is if you had Books and Libraries.  A book can belong to many Libraries and a Library can contain many books.  If I have a list (array) of libraries, how do I retrieve a unique list books that are in the list of libraries.

I feel like this code should work, but no luck...

```
Library[] libraries = some list of library ids;
List<Books> books = context.Books
                    .Where(b => libraries.Contains(b.Library.Id)
                    .ToList();
```

The issue is when I put in "b.Libraries" it give me a list option and does not let me compare to a Library.Id.

Any suggestions or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, untested - try this:

```
List<Library> libraries; // pre-populated
var booksInLibraries = context.Books
                              .Where(x => libraries.Any(y => y.Id == x.Library.Id))
                              .Distinct()
                              .ToList();
```